# Attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value) _

Tags: lua, null, self

I ran this code and it gave me an error attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)

```
hook.Add("Think", "Cooking", function()
    local Position = self:GetPos() + self:GetAngles():Up()*20
    local rawFood = ents.FindByName("my_raw_food")
    for k, v in pairs(rawFood) do
        if(Position:Distance(v:GetPos()) <= 25) then 
        v:Remove()
        timer.Create(self:EntIndex() .. "my_food", 5, 1, function() self:createFood() end)
        end
    end
end )
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to write `function(self)` instead of  `function()`.

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to say without seeing more of the code, especially the scope around your code.

But it sounds like "self" doesn't exist in the scope. Either it should be supplied as a parameter to the function:

```
hook.Add("Think", "Cooking", function(self)
  print(self)    -- uses the 'self' parameter
end)
```

or it should be available in the scope of declaring the function, and it'll be part of the closure:

```
function MyClass.addHook(self)    -- same as MyClass:addHook()
  hook.Add("Think", "Cooking", function()
    print(self)    -- uses the 'self' in scope (la MyClass instace)
  end)
```

Though, `self` can of course be `nil` even if it's declared in the scope. Calling `MyClassInstance.addHook()` instead of `MyClassInstance:addHook()` is the most common.

Comment: """MyClassInstance.addHook() instead of MyClassInstance:addHook() is the most common"""". This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

***self*** is used when using object oriented programming as described in the documentation [16 - Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html).

In order to use self you must implicitly pass it as the first argument or not.

I mean...

```
myObject = { id = 1 }
function myObject:hello( name )
  print( "hello " .. name .. " I'm object id : " .. tostring( self.id ) )
end

// Using the . char the object must be the first argument
myObject.hello( myObject, "world" )

// Using the : char the obect is automatically set as the first arg
myObject:hello( "world" )
```

So in your code, I guess you should use the : char.

```
hook:add(...)
```

Comment: I believe if `hook.Add("Think", ...)` called a function expecting `self` as first parameter, you'd get an error about `self` being a `string` (not a nil value).